# Why should I use comments when documenting python?

Tags: python, comments, docstring

There are two ways to document a module, function, or class in the code itself: `comments` and `docstrings`.

`Docstrings` are more functional, as they can be accessed via the `help()` function, while `comments` can only be accessed in the source code.

When should comments be used in place of `docstrings`?

Comment: Comments aren't documentation. Comments are for people reading the code. Documentation is for people using it.

Comment: I think the question is unclear. I mean docstrings that exist inside the source code, defined '''xxxx'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docstrings are meant to explain what a function *does*, in terms of what kinds and types of values it takes and returns, from a user's perspective.

Comments, on the other hand, being in the body of the source code, will only be visible to those actually reading it, and accordingly serve to explain *how* it does what it does.